# JPA and derby null pointer exception

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to do a simple persistence with jpa 2.0 and derby but I keep getting a NullPointerException.

Exception and entity class - http://pastebin.com/QqXhRdcN

The code where I am trying to persist

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();  
  Course c = new Course("cse", 214, "fall", 2010);  
  em.getTransaction().begin();  
  em.persist(c);  
  em.getTransaction().commit();  
  em.close();
```

The null pointer exception occurs at line 171 which is the first line of the above code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your `EntityManagerFactory` doesn't get properly created at initialization time (so it is `null`), hence the `NullPointerException` when you try to use it to obtain an `EntityManager`.

And while EclipseLink should certainly not fail with a `NPE` while trying to generate an  internationalized message for the exception (you should log this as a bug), the trace still contains useful information, as shown in bold below:

```
[EL Severe]: 2010-10-23 05:27:14.092--ServerSession(1673653)--java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.i18n.ExceptionMessageGenerator.buildMessage(ExceptionMessageGenerator.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.unableToAcquireConnectionFromDriverException(DatabaseException.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:202)
    ...
```

There is very likely something wrong with your connection pool configuration, EclipseLink isn't able to get a valid connection from it.

I can't give a more precise answer without more details about your settings like the `persistence.xml`, the Tomcat datasource configuration, the way you use Derby (in server mode?). But that's where to look.