# JPA - createEntityManagerFactory returns Null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

Noob question here. I'm following [this example/tutorial](http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started#Create%20Your%20First%20Entity) to try and isolate a problem I keep getting on my main project. Problem is, the entityManagerFactory keeps returning null (thus, I get a NullPointerExcept when trying to run the first JUnit test.)

I'm currently on Eclipse Indigo (JavaEE) - JRE7 - Hibernate 3.6.7 and JBoss 7

And here's my persistence.xml (again, a copipasta taken right from the tutorial)

```
<persistence>
        <persistence-unit name="examplePersistenceUnit" 
                          transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" 
                          value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url" 
                          value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mem:aname" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />

                <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                          value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Things I've already tried/found out so far:

- Seems this problem [tends to occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189066/jpa-entitymanager-is-not-initialized-null) if you try to create a factory
  with a persistence unit that is not listed in the persistence.xml
- Double-checked that the necessary JARs are included in Eclipse's
  Build Path Libraries, which Google suggested may be a possible cause
  for a createEntityManagerFactory() call to short-circuit and return
  null (instead of just throwing an exception or logging a message)
- Might be due to a possible error [whilst configuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003069/jpa-and-derby-null-pointer-exception) Hibernate
  connection?

I've been hitting this wall for the past couple of weeks, so it goes without saying that any help/general direction tips are MUCH appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaston, I have some suggestions/questions for you:

**1 - Is this the code you're trying to execute?**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PersonTest {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void initEmfAndEm() {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("examplePersistenceUnit");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        em.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyTest() {
    }
}
```

If it is, try to comment this line: "Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);". Or change it to "Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ALL);". Then you should see the errors on the output console.

**2 - In your persistence.xml I see you're using hsqldb database. Did you installed/configured it properly?**

If you dont't know this database, I suggest you use MySQL, PostgreSQL, or some database you are familiar with.

**3 - Check you persistence.xml. Mine is a little bite different:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="App1PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.entities.User</class>
        <class>com.entities.Group</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://myIP:3306/mydatabase"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="secret"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myUser"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Notice the header has some XML declarations that might be important, since Hibernate is telling you that your file is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply André. Unfortunately I am still stuck with the same issue (entity manager returning Null).

As suggested, I changed the loglevel to ALL and switched to MySQL (which is what I should be using anyway for my project) this is what I'm currently getting when trying to run the JUnit test:

`code`HibernatePersistence returned: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.`code`

Thank you very much for your time.

Regards,

Comment: Check my answer again, I updated the THIRD item, giving you an example of my working persistence.xml.

Comment: Better late than never :D The persistence.xml file was indeed the culprit. Ended up following André's advice (a while ago). Just came back to say THANK YOU.